# How to combine sql request with data in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, first "users_counts"

```
 id         int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
 name       varchar(250)
```

And I have second table "counts_data"

```
 id       int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
 id_user  int(11) 
 count    int(11) 
 date     datetime
```

I want to select all records from the first table and get some data from a second, and then I want to merge they. I want create temp (for one request) column where collect last count with order by date in second table and second column where collect collect penultimate count with order by date in second table.

```
INSERT INTO `users_counts` (`id`,`name`) VALUES ('1','John');
INSERT INTO `users_counts` (`id`,`name`) VALUES ('2','Michael');
INSERT INTO `users_counts` (`id`,`name`) VALUES ('3','Den');

INSERT INTO `counts_data` (`id`,`id_user`, `count`, `date`) VALUES ('1','1', '200', '2012.09.09');
INSERT INTO `counts_data` (`id`,`id_user`, `count`, `date`) VALUES ('2','1', '212', '2012.09.01');
INSERT INTO `counts_data` (`id`,`id_user`, `count`, `date`) VALUES ('3','2', '20', '2012.01.09');
INSERT INTO `counts_data` (`id`,`id_user`, `count`, `date`) VALUES ('4','3', '210', '2012.02.09');
INSERT INTO `counts_data` (`id`,`id_user`, `count`, `date`) VALUES ('5','3', '2033', '2012.03.09');
INSERT INTO `counts_data` (`id`,`id_user`, `count`, `date`) VALUES ('6','3', '1', '2012.04.09');
```

In the end, after a request I want to get something like this

```
id  name      count  count_before
1   John      200    212
2   Michael   20     0
3   Den       1      2033
```

Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible way to do this:

```
select uc.id,
       uc.name,
       (select count 
          from counts_data cd 
          where cd.id_user = uc.id
          order by date desc limit 1) as count,
       ifnull((select count 
                 from counts_data cd 
                 where cd.id_user = uc.id 
                 order by date desc limit 1 offset 1),0) as count_before
from users_counts uc;
```

Since you only need one value from the counts_data for each row/record, you can use in-line queries in mySQL

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4dd5/9)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  uc.id
,       uc.name
,       cd1.count
,       cd3.count as count_before
from    users_counts uc
left join
        counts_data cd1
on      cd1.id_user = uc.id
        and cd.date = 
        (
        select  max(date)
        from    counts_data cd2
        where   cd2.id_user = uc.id_user
        )
left join
        counts_data cd3
on      cd3.id_user = uc.id
        and cd.date = 
        (
        select  max(date)
        from    counts_data cd4
        where   cd4.id_user = uc.id_user
                and cd4.date <> cd1.date
        )
```